# Notation Clarification: $M\odot N$ for von Neumann algebras $M$ and $N$

Tags: reference-request, tensor-products, von-neumann-algebras

Given a Banach space $E$, $y\in E$, $\phi\in E^{*}$, I am led to the understanding that $y\odot \phi$ denotes the operator in $B(E)$ defined by
$$x\mapsto \phi(x)y,\text{ for all } x\in E$$

Now I have encountered the notation $M\odot N$ for von Neumann algebras $M,N$.

My instinct is to interpret in the following way: I would construct $M\odot N$, the same way I would $M\otimes N$, but with the understanding that $x\otimes y$ is defined to be the operator $x\otimes y\in B(N_{*},M)$ defined by
$$\mu\mapsto y(\mu)x,\text{ for all }\mu\in N_{*}$$

Am I close? or way off?  Is there a better way to think about this?

Any reference would be appreciated just as much as an answer!

Comment: Update:  I think that the author intended to just refer to the algebraic tensor product with this $\odot$ notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, that is another pair of shoes. It has nothing to do with the fact that von Neumann algebras are dual spaces.

Short answer: $M\odot N$ denotes the [algebraic tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_vector_spaces) of $M$ and $ N$, which has the natural structure of a *-algebra.

You probably know that each von Neumann algebra has a normal, faithful representation on some Hilbert space. Let $\pi\colon M\to B(H), \sigma\colon N\to B(K)$ be such representation. Note that $M\odot N$ has a natural representation $\pi\otimes \sigma$ on $B(H\otimes K)$, where $H\otimes K$ denotes the [tensor product of Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces), namely $$(\pi\otimes \sigma)(x\otimes y)=\pi(x)\otimes \sigma(y).$$
The tensor product of von Neumann algebras is the second commutant of the range of $\pi\otimes\sigma$.

Note that if $E$ and $F$ are Banach spaces, then you can form their [algebraic tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_vector_spaces) $E\odot F$. There is [a whole zoo of norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_tensor_product) that you can impose on that tensor product.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using $\odot$ instead of $\otimes$, aside from reserving $\otimes$ for another meaning?

Comment: Usually $\odot$ is used for the algebraic tensor product, whereas $\otimes$ is reserved for the minimal tensor product, or any other that is clear from the context.

Answer (score 0):

see Rajendra Bhatia's book "Positive Definite Matrices" page 117.